# Navbar fixed left - Bootstrap

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet, navbar

I am trying to make navbar in bootstrap to be fixed left, like on [this link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/5lapE#comments).
Anyway, it is working, but when I add block content of the leaflet map, my navbar is still there, but I can't click on it. Also, I don't get [pointer mouse](https://www.google.rs/search?q=pointer%20mouse&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidyNuPhq7dAhVrqIsKHW_CANUQ_AUICigB&biw=1259&bih=894#imgdii=75rnt6Ph_DxW8M:&imgrc=3RXYB-evATnihM:) when I cross over the link. Here is code which I changed:

```
<!--NAVBAR-->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu3</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu5</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                {% block map_content %}
                        replace me
                {% endblock map_content %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Before this, I tried more elegant solution. I used bootstrap4 and tried something like this:

```
<nav  class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-left">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}"><p class="logo_name">page name</p></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

But it doesn't work, in this case, my navbar is fixed top, and not left.

Answer (score 0):

try adding these things.  Add extra CSS to modify existing class.

Add this extra css:-

```
<style>
.navbar-fixed-left {
width: 140px;
position: fixed;
border-radius: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li {
float: none;  /* Cancel default li float: left */
width: 139px;
}

.navbar-fixed-left + .container {
padding-left: 160px;
}

/* On using dropdown menu (To right shift popuped) */
.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: 140px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I already have that CSS file from the link I put in my question.

Comment: There could be a problem while linking the css file if you are writing css on a separate file. Do you have a (base.html) file? Check if the path is correct. Try using <style></style> tag on the HTML file.

Comment: It is ok. Without leaflet block, everything works well. I get left fixed navbar which is working. With leaflet block, I also get left fixed navbar, but it doesn't work. So, it's not because of CSS file, it's because of block content I put in code (where leaflet come).